# How to write function with list of numbers as argument in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

Ho to create function in Python where I will be able to input any number of numbers like:

`xyz(1, 2, 3, 88, 10)` but also `xyz(1, 94)`, because in the body of function I will have something like: `data.query('Store in [1, 85]')`and numbers from arguments of function will go to query line. How to write this function ? Function where I will be able to input different numbers of numbers as arguments.

Below does not work:

```
def xyz(*args):
    data.query('Store in [*args]')
```

Comment: Do you want data.query('Store in args')? "args" is already a list if you starred it. No need to star it again into another list.

Comment: if you want to store a list, just convert the argument into a list

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside strings, unless you use an f-string.

Comment: `data.query('Store in ' + str(list(args)))`?

Comment: @BobbyOcean To be precise, it's a tuple.

Comment: What you're looking for is this: `list(args)`, since `args` is a `tuple` and `*args` is not a valid syntax unless used where applicable.

Comment: Try `for a in args: print(a)`. The syntax `*args` (with the asterisk) in the argument list just tells it to "absorb" all positional (non-keyword) arguments into `args`. Thereafter, `args` is a tuple. Likewise, `**kwargs` in argument list tells to absorb all keyword arguments in a dictionary-like `kwargs`.